# How to get the value of the clicked radiobutton?

Tags: jquery

There are many radiobuttons got from database in my form :

```
             ... <tr>';
                        for ( $i = $data["figure"]["cnt"] / 2; $i < $data["figure"]["cnt"]; $i++) {
                         $tabFields[4]['html'] .= '<td align="center">
                            <img src="' . HTTP_IMAGES .'figures/' . $data["figure"][$i]["fig_image"] . '" width="60px" />
                        </td>';

                        }
                    $tabFields[4]['html'] .= '  
                    </tr>
                    <tr>' ;

                        for ( $i = $data["figure"]["cnt"] / 2; $i < $data["figure"]["cnt"]; $i++) {
                        $tabFields[4]['html'] .= '
                        <td align="center">     
                        <input type="radio" name="fig_code" value="' . $data["figure"][$i]["fig_code"] . '"  />
                        </td>';

                        }
                        $tabFields[4]['html'] .= '
                    </tr>
```

I want to know the value of the radio which is clicked. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By make use of val();

```
var selected = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know the value of the radio which is clicked

If I understand the question right and *clicked* = *checked*, you want this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you to get the selected radio button's value only once the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected = $('input:radio:checked').val();
});
```

If you want to get the value of selected radio button, whenever there is a change, you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var selected = $('input:radio:checked').val();
    });
    var selected = $('input:radio:checked').val();
});
```

Comment: I bound the "change" event to all radio. So is it equivalent as your code ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to bind the change event to all the radio buttons in the page, the above given code will work.